# Char swap in a file C++

Tags: c++, replace, swap, ifstream

I dont know why this will not work, i need to swap the two chars enterd as a and b, it compiles but all the chars are replaced with the char inputted as b, any advise?

```
while (n != exist)
{
    cout<<"What is the letter you want to swap?"<<endl;
    cin>>a;             
    cout<<"What is the letter you want to swap it with?"<<endl;
    cin>>b;
    if (inFile.is_open())
    {
        while (inFile.good())
        {   
            inFile.get(c);
            if( c = a )
            {
                outFile<< b;
            }
            else if (c = b)
            {
                outFile<< a;
            }
            else
            {
                outFile<< c;
            }                               
        }                           
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Please run the decrypt."<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"Another letter? <n> to stop swapping"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `if` and `else if` you need to use `==` instead of `=`. In C++/C you use `==` for comparison and `=` for assignment.

Comment: Thanks why didnt i see that i have no idea works as i want it!!

Comment: @DominicBarrett: You might want to look into turning up your compile warnings to point out this kind of error.

Answer (score 7):

```
if( c == a )
{
    outFile<< b;
}
else if (c == b)
{
    outFile<< a;
}
```

`=` is for assignment, use `==` for comparison.

The way you have it, as long as a is not 0(the integer 0, not the character '0'), that first branch will always be executed.

Answer (score 7):

`if( c = a )` and `else if (c = b)` are suspect. You are assigning the value of a to c and the value of b to c, respectively. I believe if the assignment operation completes successfully (which is it), the block will execute. I believe you want the `==` operator, instead of the `=` operator.

Comment: i will now it takes 10 mins before i can

Answer (score 6):

You are assigning values instead of testing.

It should be

`if (c == b)`

and

`if (c == a)`